# Joda DateTime not supported property type in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jodatime

Hi I'm just starting with Google App Engine and this bug is beyond me.

Trying to use Joda DataTime with Google App Engine.  I have an entity which holds a dateTime and I get the the error when it reaches em.close(); The error reads "sentTime: org.joda.time.DateTime is not a supported property type."

```
        EntityManagerFactory emf = EMF.get();
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
                     List<Tasks> schedule = patients2.getTasks();
                     Tasks tasks = new Tasks();
                     String date = req.getParameter("dateTime")+":00.000-00:00";   DateTime sentTime = new DateTime (date);
                     tasks.setSentTime(sentTime);
                     schedule.add(tasks);
                     patients2.setTasks(schedule);
                     em.persist(patients2);
            }

        }
        }finally {
            if (em != null)
                em.close();
        }
```

and the stack trace is

```
WARNING: /CreateSchedule
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: sentTime: org.joda.time.DateTime is not a supported property type.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedSingleValue(DataTypeUtils.java:235)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:207)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:173)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DataTypeUtils.checkSupportedValue(DataTypeUtils.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PropertyContainer.setProperty(PropertyContainer.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.setEntityProperty(EntityUtils.java:174)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeFieldInEntity(StoreFieldManager.java:360)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeObjectField(StoreFieldManager.java:190)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1447)
    at healith.Tasks.jdoProvideField(Tasks.java)
    at healith.Tasks.jdoProvideFields(Tasks.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.provideFields(AbstractStateManager.java:1515)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:241)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.flush(JDOStateManager.java:3778)
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataNucleus project (used by GAE JDO/JPA) has a plugin for persisting such types. Perhaps you could put it in the CLASSPATH.
http://www.datanucleus.org/plugins/store.types.jodatime.html

Downloadable from [Maven central](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/datanucleus/datanucleus-jodatime/). Pick the most appropriate version for whichever version of GAE you're using. Put it in the CLASSPATH is all you do. Look at the LOG if you have problems since it will say whether that plugin is registered at runtime.

Comment: Can this work by only including the datanucleus mvn dependency in the pom.xml? I don't see how putting it on windows' classpath is going to help it work on GAE.

Comment: Also, if the datanucleus is ultimately just tranforming between java.util.Date and JodaTime's DateTime, I'm guessing the timezone will be lost, which is one reason I want to use JodaTime. True?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Objectify in my project and that has a way to allow Joda DateTime as entity properties.

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.impl.translate.opt.joda.JodaTimeTranslators;

// immediately before your entity registrations
JodaTimeTranslators.add(factory());
```

Comment: I confirm that this works. JodaTimeTranslators.add(ObjectifyService.factory())

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the error you'll see that when storing the entity into the DB it complains that  Joda's `DateTime` is not one of supported property types.

With JPA on GAE the [supported property types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview-dn2#Class_and_Field_Annotations) are: one of the [basic DB types](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities#Java_Properties_and_value_types), a `Collection` of those basic types or another Entity.

Comment: Correct, until they put a plugin in the classpath that converts such types into one of the "supported types" of course.

Comment: Sorry dataNucleus newb here can you tell me exactly how to install/incorporate dataNucleus plugins. I've downloaded the dataNuclues eclipse plugin and tried to install the jars from the link but it seems that with GAE engine you need to do something above and beyond.  Do I need to go into the a specific plugin.xml files and do something manually or is it much simpler than this? help always appreciated

Comment: @Frido1, no idea what the DN Eclipse plugin has to do with anything here; you asked how to persist Jodatime types, so I said put the datanucleus-jodatime plugin in your CLASSPATH.

Comment: By plugin I was thinking a plugin in the terms of something that needs to be installed. Thanks for your help!